# How to make several sprite nodes each with a special path to follow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game like flight control where there are x amount of cars and each one has its own path to follow.  My idea was to make a car class of subtype SKNode and have a CGMutablePathRef instance variable for each object.  I can make the CGMutablePathRef with touchsBegins, touchsMoved, and touchesEnded and figured I could then have each object follow its specific path with the SKAction followPath.  Is this a good approach?  If not how would you do it?  This is what I have so far for the Vehicle class:

Vehicle.h

```
@interface Vehicle: SKNode

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGMutablePathRef pathToFollow;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat speed;
@property (nonatomic) int direction;

- (instancetype)initWith:(CGMutablePathRef)pathPassed;

@end
```

Vehicle.m

```
@implementation Vehicle : SKNode

@synthesize pathToFollow;
@synthesize speed;
@synthesize direction;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        SKSpriteNode *vehicle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        [self addChild:vehicle];
        [self setDirection:4];
        [vehicle setName:@"car"];
        [self setScale:.5];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWith:(CGMutablePathRef)pathPassed {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        SKSpriteNode *vehicle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        [self addChild:vehicle];
        [self setPathToFollow:pathPassed];
        [self setDirection:4];
        [vehicle setName:@"car"];
        [self setScale:.1];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

EDIT: Adding GameScene in hopes that it will help.  I am having a problem with my implementation now where the Vehicle object is following the path but only after it jumps up to the coordinates of the first point + the nodes position on the scene (ex: position = (200, 200), first point = (123, 456) it will go to (323, 656) then follow the path).  It draws the line where I want it but then it follows from way up on this coordinate.  Thanks again for the help!

GameScene.m

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    _car = [[Vehicle new] init]; // init the Vehicle object then set position
    [_car setPosition:CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2, self.scene.size.height/2)];
    [self addChild_car]; // add the child to the scene
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // get the node that was touched
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    _nodeTouchedFirst = [self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];

    if ([_nodeTouchedFirst.name isEqualToString:@"car"]) {
        if (lineNode != NULL) { // remove the previous path
            [lineNode removeFromParent];
            [CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
        }

        //Start a new path and display it on the screen
        pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
        lineNode = [SKShapeNode];
        lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
        lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
        [self addChild:lineNode];


    }
} // touchesBegan

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if ([_nodeTouchedFirst.name isEqualToString:@"car"]) {
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
        lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    }
} // touchesMoved

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([_nodeTouchedFirst.name isEqualToString:@"car"]) {
        SKAction *followPath = [SKAction followPath:pathToDraw asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:2];
        [_nodeTouchedFirst runAction:followPath];
        lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor grayColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your current code do what you need it to do?

Comment: No not really. On my gamescene.m I will initialize a Vehicle object and try to do the SKAction in touchesEnded and what happens is it will warp up and to the right for some reason and then start following the path.

Comment: Post the init and touchesEnded code form your GameScene.

Comment: Just did.  I also found the coordinates its going to before following the path if that helps at all but it seems like arbitrary numbers to me.  Is it the CGPathMoveToPoint bit inside the touchesBegan method?  I will play around with it and see if thats why

Comment: Figured out the problem where it wasn't follow the path from the right spot.  I needed to change the asOffset from YES to NO in the SKAction followPath method.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations that may or may not help:

- You're setting the position of `_car` and adding it to the scene before you give it a path to follow.
- You're referencing both `_nodeTouchedFirst` and `nodeTouchedFirst`, `"car"` and `"car1"`.
- You're following a path with `asOffset:YES, orientToPath:NO, duration:2` (rather than `asOffset:NO, orientToPath:YES, speed:2`).
- `direction` doesn't correspond to the `SKNode zRotation` property.

Comment: Yea most of that was errors when i was copying it over.  I haven't started working with direction yet that will be where the user needs to direct the car but I haven't gotten there yet.  All I am trying to do now is to move the skspritenode I made and positioned to whever i drag and draw to but like I said int he commends it seems to follow the path but only after jumping up to some weird coordinates.  Ill fix the typos though, thanks!

Comment: `nodeTouchedFirst` and `car` aside, what of the other points?  For example, having the node follow a path that doesn't begin at its current position seems relevant to what you may be experiencing.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to have it do.  Im trying to make it to where the user can click the node and draw a path for it to follow and the node follows after the user lets go of the click.  Like I said it will follow the path but only after it warps up to some weird coordinates which isn't what I want.

Comment: But in your didMoveToView(_:) method you appear to first place the car in the middle of the scene. I'm suggesting you either wait to add it to the scene until you have a path for it to follow or make the scene center your first CGPathMoveToPoint.

Comment: Yea I put it there just for testing reasons to see if I could makes it move when I click it and draw a path.  I tried CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2) if that is what you mean by make the scene center my first point.  It still moved up and to the right.  I did however notice that where it moves before following the path depends on the first point.  When I start at middle of the scene it goes to double that position (so from self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 to 2*(self.frame.size.width/2), 2*(self.frame.size.height/2))

Comment: Also I know the first point isn't the one that is 2x where it starts because if it was, the line I draw from the path would start way over there but it starts where i want it.

Comment: Figured it out.  It was because of the asOffset parameter.  So simple haha I cannot believe it took me that long to realize I just needed to change 'YES' to 'NO'.

Comment: One more question though.  As touchesMoved picks up new coordinates I have noticed each touch it picks up is a change in either the x or the y and not both.  When I change the orientToPath parameter to YES the car is very jumpy on the curves.  Is there a way to make these lines more curved and less jumpy?

Comment: Create curves using `CGPathAddCurveToPoint` instead of `CGPathAddLineToPoint`. This requires a small amount of overhead as you will need to collect 3 points for each call.

Comment: But if touchesMoved only changes either x or y won't it be a line regardless?  I guess what I am trying to say is if my last touch was at say (100, 100) and moved my touch up to (110, 110) it seems like touches moved will do it 2 different times so it'll go (100, 100) to (110, 100) to (110, 110) which makes the car look spastic when it travels those 2 lines as opposed to what would be the hypotenuse of those 3 points.

Comment: That both x and y are not different for each touch event is unusual and perhaps indicative of some other issue. Regardless, a moveTo point of (100, 100) followed by curve points of, say, (110, 110), (110, 90), (120, 100) will produce a smooth Bezier curve path.